# Dot notation confusion

Tags: objective-c, syntax

After learning some Objective-C, I still remain confused about the dot notation.

I understand using the dot notation in "setters" and "getters", I am OK with that part. However, I have the habit to use `_varableName` whenever I am not setting or getting the value. Some examples from my code:

`.h` file:

```c
@property (nonatomic,strong) LoginWindowController *loginWindow;
@property (nonatomic,strong) MainWindowController *mainWindowController;
```

`.m` file:

```c
_loginWindow = [[LoginWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"LoginWindowController"];
[[_mainAppViewController view]removeFromSuperview];
```

Should I use the dot notation in the above examples? For some reason, am not seeing the sense in using `self.loginWindow` or `self.mainAppViewController`.

Comment: Yes, because you might want to implement the accessor methods in future

Comment: It's not as big a deal for the class itself, because if you implement a getter and/or setter *and want to use it*, you can just change the class yourself.  Where it really matters is if a *subclass* implements a getter or setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices are to use the dot notation whenever you get/set a property (except in init methods.)

Why?

Using dot notation (or value/setValue:) enforces the property attributes (the "nonatomic" and "strong" bits) whereas direct access bypasses them. KVO also requires that you use the property to work properly.

You don't use it in init methods because sub-classes might override the the methods and deal with bits of code that will not have been properly initialized yet.

Comment: So in the code that I posted, I should use the dot notation in mainWindowController but I am ok to use _loginWindow, since I am doing initialization. But what should I do in next line when I use login window? I should use dot notation there?

Comment: If the line of code is *in* an initializer, then use direct access. Otherwise use dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're confused is that ARC is managing memory for you. This wasn't always the case.

Thus, in the old days, the accessor method (which is what the property and dot-notation really give you) had actual memory management code in it. If you bypassed the accessor and accessed the instance variable directly, you were heading for trouble when you messed up memory management, which was now up to you. Therefore, it was better in general to use the accessor / property / dot-notation.

Now, however, ARC steps in and gives you strong-reference memory management even when you assign directly to the instance variable. Thus, even though it's not a great habit, the penalty is not so clearcut.